# How to use Google Drive as a sort of CDN

Tags: google-drive-api, cdn

So, what I'm trying to do is load up some resource files (.js, .css, etc.) to Google Drive.  Basically, I'd like to use my Google Drive this as a sort of CDN.  Is this possible?  When I upload say, a .js file, I'd like to get a direct link (http://drive.google.com/test/test.js, for example).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Drive CSS Returns 404 Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478447/google-drive-css-returns-404-error)

Answer (score 9):

With images is easy: 
Upload it, then click preview.
In Chrome (crtl+shift+J) or in firefox get the html text from that image: u will have something like:

```
<img src="https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=0B6czwVjwSt48SDJNRWZZWlFmZmM&amp;authuser=0&amp;v=1412661926713&amp;sz=w1475-h579" class="a-c-ub-Aa a-c-Ma-td-Ib" alt="Displaying Koala.jpg" aria-hidden="true">
```

Then open that url in other tab (still using your gmail account), you will notice that you will open the image and obtain a new URL.
This new URL is visible to open with non authenticated google account... this means that it is public.....

```
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/SuA7NGIYC7uVg7XsIYnYSHEIDnTkLfa04Hm9dPSz8tbZZULdrxVMMIcB6MWTIXHGb0FKTQ=s220
```

And this is the way you can use it for hosting images.