# HTML to run javascript on wordpress site

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Leader Makers Leadership Addessment
    </title>

    <!-- (A) LOAD QUIZ CSS + JS -->
    <link href="quiz.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/h96acg5jbwidphm/quiz.js"></script>
<STYLE>
H1 { text-align: center; background: #cf1a1f;
  color: #fff}
  
</STYLE>
  </head>
  <body>
<H1>Leader Makers Leadership Level Assessment</H1>
    <!-- (B) QUIZ CONTAINER -->
  <div id="quizWrap"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to run a JavaScript stored on my google drive but it does not run if I replace the `src` with just the file name it works fine.

If there is a alternative way to run the script and CSS on my WordPress site please share the same.

Comment: Have tried with the link to google drive also but it does not work

Comment: I tried to copy and paste the script to the head tag under <script></script> but it does not work as it does on my desktop.

Comment: Ok. Understood. Try using this as your link: `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={fileID}` remember to replace {fileId} with the fileId. If `https://drive.google.com/file/d/13g8OJmkTStwJ-oU-0VB-0yvL2BebVE1Z/view?usp=sharing` is a share then the id is: `13g8OJmkTStwJ-oU-0VB-0yvL2BebVE1Z`

Comment: This does not load either

Comment: And yes. Use a wp plugin to add the script it to head tag.

Comment: Tried it with script tag?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231815/discussion-between-mohammad-kamrul-hasan-and-ish).

Answer (score 0):

If you host a file more than some MBs, than g drive shows you an html file as a notice that it could not scan the file for virus. If you copy download link after downloading, then you will see that it is a temporary link, but you might be able to host images in it. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992241/how-to-use-google-drive-as-a-sort-of-cdn/30759755#30759755)). But you can use github repo for this purpose. See more here: https://gomakethings.com/how-to-turn-any-github-repo-into-a-cdn

Comment: Thank You so much it did work with github but now I am facing a challenge with css the wrapper is overlapping the footer on desktop and getting misplaced on mobile. trying to fix it now